# Parsing a json nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, json

I need to reach the value "y "of "B" in result.

```
{
       "Response": {
                  "Result": [2]
                          0:  {
                                "A": "x"
                                "B": "y"
                                "C": "z"
                              }
                          1:  {
                                "A": "d"
                                "B": "e"
                                "C": "f"
                                "D": "g"
                              }

                    }
}
```

my attempt **['Response']['Result'][0]['B']** produces the given error

> IndexError: list index out of range

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't valid json. Nor is it a valid dictionary. Something around `"Result":[2]` isn't right. It looks like there's a missing comma, but that wouldn't match your error message.

Comment: Please include the actual JSON - there aren't *any* commas here, and `0` and `1` are formatted as mapping keys but there is no mapping containing them.

Answer (score 2):

The key `0` is not under `"Result"` you should use `['Response'][0]['B']`

Comment: ['Response'][0]['B'] gives a Key Error

Comment: I would listen to the comments to your question, and supply a correctly formatted JSON.  It also seems strange to me that you initially got an `IndexError` using `['Response']['Result'][0]` as it would imply you had an empty list. However, since you now get a `KeyError` I would suggest trying to see what output you get from `['Response'][0]`